# XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /usr/local/firefox/libxul.so

Tags: firefox, centos, headless

When running firefox on centos. I am getting the following error. How do i resolve this?

```
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /usr/local/firefox/libxul.so:
libdbus-glib-1.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Couldn't load XPCOM.
```

Comment: I have this exact error, did you find a solution?